# How to pass data from one view to other view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi have a scenario where in i have 3 views in the first view i have some textbox and then next button on click of next button the second view will be shown and the second view will also have some textbox and next button the third view is the final view which has few textboxes and submit/finish button. On click of submit/finish button all the data from view1,view2 and view3 should be saved to database. How to achieved it using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Is it 3 separate views or in a single view 3 separate panel/pane/div something like that ??

Comment: Using shared viewmodel for all 3 forms and `Session`/`TempData` which hold all inputs from previously inserted forms should be applicable. On the last form you can write logic to insert data into DB based from values stored in viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass data from one view to another view then you can use **TempData**
ex.
     TempData["Key"] = "test";

and can get value from tempdata like

```
@{
   var abc = TempData["Key"];
}
```

**Note:** You can get tempdata value to next action after that it will be destroy.

Comment: How many tempdata i need to create suppose i have around 50 fields in the first form then in this case i need to create 50 tempdata ?.

Comment: You can also pass object or collection to temp data for example TempData["SaveMsg"] = new object[]{model.ImageUrl , model.Name};

Comment: here object will be your model and in your view you can cast to your model from temp data. so you don't need multiple tempdata for single form field

Answer (score 0):

You can use temp-data and their keep method to persist data in subsequent request.
Just keep all required field data into temp-data and get all this in one object(temp-data) and save them

Answer (score 0):

Here is an eg. for it:

```
public ActionResult Add(Model model)
{
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Model.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Add2");
            }
            return View(model);
}
```

it redirects to the second view or a partial view, and the same with the 2nd to the 3rd. Hope it helps.